# Newbie jquery syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you pls tell me what's wrong with this line of code? (returning an error). Thanks

```
jQuery('.menu').slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuad', function();
```

Full code is:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('blockquote').quovolver();

    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.menu').slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuad', function();
    jQuery('#newsbox').delay(2000).slideDown();
    jQuery('.newsClose').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#newsbox').slideUp();

    }); 
});     
</script>
```

Comment: Are you missing the start in `script type='...'>` (`<`)?

Comment: What is the error? you have a miss-matched `(`, and your function definition is incomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

Change this...

```
jQuery('.menu').slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuad', function();
```

For this...

```
jQuery('.menu').slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuad', function(){});
```

Comment: Or `jQuery('.menu').slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuad');`, since passing an empty function as a callback is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to put `{ });`

```
jQuery('.menu').slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuad', function(){
   // stuff to do when slideDown completed
});
```

You can always use the docs to learn proper syntax

- http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined a function for "function()."  Define one like you did for .newsClose.

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem in this line:

```
jQuery('.menu').slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuad', function();
```

There's a typo here—you forgot the closing paren to `.slideDown(` after `function()`. But you can just take out the anonymous function entirely:

```
jQuery('.menu').slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuad');
```

In this case, the third parameter to `.slideDown` is a callback function. [This parameter is optional.](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) It looks like you don't want to call another function after the slide down animation, so don't pass a third parameter at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be the function()  call. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.menu').slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuad', function() {
        jQuery('#newsbox').delay(2000).slideDown();
        jQuery('.newsClose').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery('#newsbox').slideUp();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your code should be this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('blockquote').quovolver();
    jQuery('.menu').slideDown(1000, 'easeOutQuad', function(){
      jQuery('#newsbox').delay(2000).slideDown();
      jQuery('.newsClose').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         jQuery('#newsbox').slideUp();
      });
    }); 
});       
</script>
```

this code is completely indented and it is how it should be compare with yours and you will come to know all the mistakes done

Pointing the mistakes you did-

1. the script tag was not correctly started `script...` to `<script...`
2. `$(document).ready(...` should ideally be used once *Note*: Best practice , not an error
3. every jQuery function if have a call back have syntax like `$(elem).func(params,callback);`

   - if you are passing the callback function with a name, it will be like `$(elem).func(params,functionName);`
   - if you are defining there itself use `function(){}` and this will become `$(elem).func(params,function(){});`
   - this will be indented to

> $(elem).func(params,function(){
>         // your code
>    });

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Rohit. Appreciate it.